analytical solution to a toy-sized but interesting optimization problem
My question follows after the initial context.
My research includes solving a subproblem many many times - maximizing the Euclidean distance between a pair of convex neighborhoods, e.g. between an ellipsoid and a bounded elliptical paraboloid in 3D; an example in 2D might be a circle and a bounded single sheet ($y\ge0$) of a vertical hyperbola. I include two example images.  One shows two ellipsoids with linear halfspaces having cut off part of the region.  The other shows a parabola and a sheet of an hyperbola.
I currently have 2 means of solving this:

locally-optimal NLP solvers such as CONOPT and SNOPT (via GAMS) where I use a partitioning scheme for each neighborhood's exterior to find the global optimum.
a geometric search heuristic that converges to the globally optimal solution as verified by KKT conditions (it's trivial to ensure I'm in the local neighborhood that contains the globally optimal KKT solution).  I'm considering trying to implement an SQP algorithm like a mini-SNOPT but that would be a massive undertaking and unlikely to succeed.

I'm unsatisfied for 3 reasons.

Method 1 is too slow calling GAMS from a C++ application and it costs 5-10k to purchase SNOPT as a dll to call directly (which would be fast enough).
Method 2 for 3D neighborhoods where the two neighborhoods aren't quite "similar" (e.g. ellipsoid radii are all nearly the same, etc.) I converge only to about ~e-5 KKT condition feasibility whereas I'd prefer the ~e-10 to e-14 range I get for ellipses, parabolae, and hyperbolae.  It also is tricky to prove I correctly always converge - I do not like that it is formally a 'heuristic'.
Finally, for a problem this "toylike" in size (distance between two neighborhoods), really, I simply can't believe there isn't a closed-form analytical solution that avoids the numerical difficulties I cope with.  I suspect I'm missing something elementary.

Now for many reasons related to problem ill-conditioning:
For method 1, I express the problem to a math programming solver like SNOPT in the following way:

quadratic feasibility is checked in what I call unit-canonical space...e.g. any arbitrary ellipsoid can be transformed into an axis-aligned unit sphere where the feasibility constraint is nothing more than $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1$.  This matters for other versions of the problem where I minimize/maximize path distance through a fixed series of such neighborhoods, many of which may be of radically different size.
bounding halfspaces are input in what I call canonical space: e.g. any arbitrary ellipsoid can be rotated and translated such that its origin is at $(0,0,0)$ and the ellipsoid axes align with the Cartesian x-, y-, and z-axes.
the Euclidean distance (the objective function) is expressed in what I call general space; distance calculated here is the true distance.

For my solution method 2, I express everything in unit-canonical space including deriving the KKT conditions and subsequent iterates.  E.g. searching around a unit-sphere is far more stable for my algorithm than searching around the equivalent untransformed ellipsoid with radii a few orders of magnitude different length.
I've tried and failed to analytically solve the KKT condition equations using the method of Lagrange multipliers but that could be because 1) I'm doing it wrong, 2) it actually has no closed-form solution, or 3) I'm missing some basic method that's actually possible.
My question: could someone work out and demonstrate a way to solve this analytically (using alglib, e.g.)?  I would certainly cite your work.
My only stipulation is to not use "easy" cases such as circles/spheres invariant to rotation and the like. 2D ellipse-to-ellipse or 3D ellipsoid-to-ellipsoid is most preferable please.  I can post the KKT conditions (expressed in unit-canonical space) if requested.
Thank you!

I'm not going to call it "solved" just yet, but here's what I've found. ALGLIB now has an SQP implementation that handles nonlinear constrained programs (the last time I'd checked a few years ago, it did not, at least I had thought it didn't).  I can call that directly and get outstanding performance with one caveat.  Even with the most stringent termination conditions, the answer for 'harder' problems is usually KKT-feasible at about 1e-3 to 1e-6...not what I like.  Even if the objective function remains the same, i want the probably optimal at machine epsilon (I use ~1e-13).

I found I could create an NLP to minimize KKT infeasibility (this works and only involves a few inner iterations of QP solving) but Sergei Bochkanov (thank you) suggested performing some Newton-Raphson iterations...and at the end, that seems to work EXTREMELy well.
